# Read avro file records in map reduce irrespective of schema

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, avro, cloudera-cdh

I need to write a map reduce program which reads avro files from entire hdfs files.My mapper code input will be different avro files having different schema. In my mapper part of my code I need to read the entire record of files irrespective of the file schema. Could anyone tell me how we can achieve reading a entire record from avro.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I think this is doable. Not sure what you are trying to achieve but let say you want to do something to records backed by the same schema.

In your mapper, read bytes and get the schema json.  Here is an example how you can get the schema: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader
The key out of the mapper would be the schema json string and the value would be the record (bytes). Then in your reducer you would have all the same schemas together and you would be able to use GenericRecord to deserialize the data using the provided schema and do whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks Marcin I have used PigAvroInputFormat bundled with Pig AvroStorage.